# Way to find device orientation change after calling `setRequestedOrientation`

Tags: android, android-orientation

Is there any way in Android to know device orientation change after we call `setRequestedOrientation`, I have tried following ways.

1. `getResources().getConfiguration().orientation`
2. `OrientationEventListener`
3. `Display getOrient = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();`

But all the above methods are give same values even after changing the device orientation.
Can someone please suggest some way by which we can find the device orientation change after we call `setRequestedOrientation`.

Comment: have you found any solution? have the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a *workaround*: Handle onOrientationChanged degree from OrientationEventListener added to currente context. For example:

```
final OrientationEventListener orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener( getApplicationContext() ) {

    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged( final int orientation ) {
        Log.i( "orientation_test", "orientation: " + orientation );
    }
};

orientationEventListener.enable();
```

Add and enable it at onResume and disable at onPause of Activity for example.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    // Do something
else
    // Do something else
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question "getConfiguration().orientation" method does not return the proper orientation value when we change the orientation.